# Airflow with KubernetesExecutor slowly runs DAG tasks

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

We have Airflow working with KubernetesExecutor.

And it takes a lot of time to just start a new task on schedule.
That's a usual state when a couple of dags must be started at same time, but a lot of tasks are in state "queued":

[image: Tasks queue]

It looks like we have not enough workers, but our devops says that there is a separate worker for each dag task.

On the image below we can see that total DAG execution time is 1:57:

[image: DAG execution duration]

But each task execution time in sum is at maximum 3 seconds.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Any ideas why it takes so much time to just start a task?
I think that there is some problem with Kubernetes or its configuration, but have no proofs and have no competency to prove it.

P.S. I am not from DevOps team, so unfortunatelly I do not have access to server or kubernetes configuraion, but I can ask for it on demand.

P.P.S On previous server with LocalExecutor everything worked as expected, without delays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kubernetes executor spins up a new pod for each task, which includes the startup time for Airflow's worker process. During that startup time, the task will be in the "queued" state. Depending on your Kubernetes setup and the nature of the worker pod you are trying to spin up, start up times of 2 minutes are not unheard of. Your best bet to determine what's causing the time is to watch it on K8s with your ops team, it may be in the Pending state or it could be Running but going through the Airflow start up.

The LocalExecutor, by contrast has none of that start up time, so it makes sense that tasks start faster on the LocalExecutor.

Comment: Sorry for rookie question, but could you please elaborate, what eactly should be checked in k8s? the state of pod on which the task should be executed?
Also, is there a way not to shut down pods after task is complete? The more DAGs we have - the bigger the delay is, that's dissapointing. Looks like just a few (or maybe one?) pod is activating at a time, I don't think it works as intended.

Comment: The pods ought to shut down after completing by default. I was referring to checking the state of the worker pods trying to start in K8s, yes. 

One other thing to check is to make sure that your DAG file can parse quickly. Sometimes delays happen when DAGs are written to make http requests in the top level code and it takes forever to parse.

Answer (score 1):

A hybrid DAG (both celery-executor and kubernetes-executor were used):
[image: performance]

### Reduce `spin up` duration and enhance concurrency

#### 1. Optimize `spin up` duration

Pay attention to `pip install` during the initialization stage.
Build your own `worker` image while not install extra-dependencies during initialization stage.
If you specify an additional `requirements.txt` in your deployment, every `worker` pod runs a `pip install -r <your-extra-requirements.txt>` command during the initialization stage, which can be time-consuming.
It's better to build all your extra dependencies into your `worker` image.

#### 2. Enhance concurrency

##### 2.1 **Lower** resources requests

Specify **lower** resources requests for `worker` pod in your deployment.
You can inherit the default pod template in your tasks and specify adaptable resource requests.
Resources requests can prevent k8s from creating more pods under concurrency conditions.
BTW, if you have many tiny tasks in your dags, and also small portion require runtime isolation, an `CeleryKubernetesExecutor` may be better.

##### 2.2 Configurations influence pods creation

refer to: [configurations on kubernetes-executor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/configurations-ref.html#kubernetes-executor)
There are many configurations can influence pods creation, for example:

```
[scheduler]
scheduler_heartbeat_sec = 5
[kubernetes_executor]
worker_pods_creation_batch_size = 10 # Default 1. Indicate how many pods can be created in a heartbeat term. Change this value according to your cluster.
```

### Summary:

**√ Recommended:**

- √ Build your own image
- √ *No*/*Lower* resources requests in deployment
- √ Inherit the default pod template and specify resource requests in tasks

**× Not recommended:**

- × Mount an extra `requirements.txt`
- × Specify high resource requests for worker pods

### Example for bitnami/airflow

#### Build

```
# A base Dockerfile for airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-worker
# The BASE_IMAGE should be bitnami/airflow, bitnami/airflow-scheduler, or bitnami/airflow-worker
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
USER root
ENV TZ=<your-timezone> \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    PIP_INDEX_URL=<your-pip-server>
COPY requirements.txt /custom/requirements.txt
RUN source /opt/bitnami/airflow/venv/bin/activate && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r /custom/requirements.txt && \
    deactivate
USER 1001
```

#### Deployment

```yaml
# portion of `values.yaml` for `helm install`
executor: CeleryKubernetesExecutor
redis:
  enabled: true
rbac:
  create: true
serviceAccount:
  create: true
  name: "<SPECIFY A SERVICE ACCOUNT>"
extraEnvVarsCM: "airflow-common-envs-configmap"
extraDeploy:
- |
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: airflow-common-envs-configmap
  data:
    ## [apache-airflow-providers-celery](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-celery/stable/configurations-ref.html)
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__WORKER_AUTOSCALE: "1,16"
    AIRFLOW__CELERY_KUBERNETES_EXECUTOR__KUBERNETES_QUEUE: "kubernetes"
## Lower resources requests
worker:
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: 2.0
      memory: 4Gi
    requests:
      cpu: 100m
      memory: 500Mi
  autoscaling:
    enabled: true
    minReplicas: 1
    maxReplicas: 2
```

### Example for DAGs developing(local)

1. config

```
# portion of ~/airflow/airflow.cfg
[core]
executor = LocalKubernetesExecutor # For quick debugging
[kubernetes_executor]
config_file = <your kube config file path>
in_cluster = False # airlfow doesn't run in a k8s cluster
namespace = debug # worker namespace
pod_template_file = # you can get a pod_template_file from DevOpsTeam and edit it as your own pod_template_file
[local_kubernetes_executor]
kubernetes_queue = kubernetes
```

2. DAG

```py
@task
def execute_local():
    pass

@task(queue='kubernetes')
def execute_in_dedicated_pod():
    pass

templated_with_specified_resources={
        "pod_override": k8s.V1Pod(
            spec=k8s.V1PodSpec(
                containers=[
                    k8s.V1Container(
                        name="base",
                        volume_mounts=[
                            k8s.V1VolumeMount(mount_path="/example/", name="example")
                        ],
                        resources=k8s.V1ResourceRequirements(
                            requests={"cpu": "500m", "memory": "800Mi"},
                            limits={"cpu": "1", "memory": "1Gi"},
                        ),
                    ),
                ],
                volumes=[
                    k8s.V1Volume(
                        name="example",
                        empty_dir=k8s.V1EmptyDirVolumeSource(size_limit="10Mi"),
                    )
                ],
            )
        ),
    }
@task(queue='kubernetes', executor_config=templated_with_specified_resources):
def execute_in_dedicated_pod_and_request_resources():
    pass
```